# regex: How to filter this numeric combo pasw?

Tags: regex

for example:

```
john@yahoo.com:abcd123
john@yahoo.com:1234
john@yahoo.com:abcd
john@yahoo.com:123abcd
```

I want to exclude lines which end with numbers and keep only these two lines:

```
john@yahoo.com:abcd
john@yahoo.com:123abcd
```

I have a regex code I tried, but it doesn't work, I use this tool-->  Word List Updater 2.7

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}:(?=.*[a-z]{8,})(?=.^\d))
```

Comment: This should do it: `[^\d]$` (or perhaps `[^0-9]$`)

Comment: but you want to whole passw was lenght 8 or more, or just letters? because with [a-z]{8,} it will match only passw with 8 small case letters, and it will not match string you give us as valid

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I didn't see that @Sobrique has already commented the correct answer while I tried out the regex.

You could just use `\d$`.

It does match all numbers that are immediately followed by a linebreak. So if your string matches this rule, it can be tossed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}:[a-z\d]*[a-z]$/mig
```

Working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jV1hG3/1)

Answer (score 0):

If it is about matching a string with password of proper lenght and content, try with:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}:(?=[\da-z]*?[a-z]$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zY4oV8/1)

if you also want to match password, use:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}:(?=[\da-z]*?[a-z]$)(.+)
```

and if password has to be proper length, use this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}:(?=(?:[\da-z]*?[a-z]){4,}$)
```

or if you want to match this constrained password, use:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}:(?=[\da-z]*?[a-z]$)(.{4,})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zY4oV8/2)

where `.{4,}` means, that it has to be at least 4 characters.